# AuditIgnore on part of from body

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core-2.2, audit.net

I have a method that returns saves a user to the identity table. I would like to audit to check who is creating the users but not audit the password.

```
public async Task<IActionResult> RegisterUser([FromBody]NewUser register)
{
 //code for creation of new user
 }
```

If I use `[AuditIgnore][FromBody]NewUser register` the username is not displayed.

I pass the username in the comment field like so

```
public async Task<IActionResult> RegisterUser([AuditIgnore][FromBody]NewUser register)
{
 //code for creation of new user
  var auditScope = this.GetCurrentAuditScope();
  auditScope.Comment($"user is {register.Username}");
 }
```

However, it would be nice to display it with the rest of the data.

Answer (score 1):

I have figured it out before I return the token and after I check username/password is valid I have set `login.Password = null;`. This is then not returned in the audit log

This is what gets returned

```
"ActionParameters": {
  "login": {
    "Username": "new user"
  }
},
```